# how do you make things random only once per time drawn in p5?

Tags: p5.js

I am trying to make my variable random once per time drawn

Comment: When asking a question on StackOverflow you should include more details on what you are trying to do, you should include code examples, and you should indicate what you have tried. So far your question indicates no effort whatsoever to find an answer to your question through your own research.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why this warrants a question on StackOverflow, simply assign the variable a random value in the your draw() function. One way to do this is using the [`random()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random).

```js
let x;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  // slow down the frame rate so the circle doesn't jump around so quickly.
  frameRate(2);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  x = random(0, width);
  circle(x, height / 2, 40);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```